# Prove that the subset of $L_2$ is precompact

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to answer the question whether the subset $ x : \int_0^1{|x(s)|^2ds \leq  1, |x(t) - x(s)| \leq |t-s| }$ is precompact.

My first attempt was to try using Showder basis, however there was an $n$ in the denominator. Using criteria did not help either…

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzelà–Ascoli_theorem This would help you, and I believe all $x$ should be defined on $[0,1]$

Comment: What are the $x$ referenced in your question? Are they continuous functions on $[0, 1]$? And precompact in what topology? $L^2$ or uniform norm?